# Custom column intervals in a PGFPlots histogram

Tags: pgfplots

Is is possible to give columns in a PGFPlots histogram custom interval of different sizes? Eg. I would like my histogram to have five columns over these intervals:

```
[-100,-50[
[-50,0[
[0,1[
[1,50[
[50,100[
```

So that `0` has a single column, preferably as wide as the other columns.

I cannot upload the exact diagram I am currently using, but this example from the pgfplots gallery is close enough:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar interval,
  xticklabel=
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
        table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 
        7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\ 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would then like to specify the intervals for the data instead of just setting the number of bins and letting pgfplot figure it out.

Comment: Can you show exactly what the result should look like? 

Paint drawing etc.